# right outer join issue in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to get the data from four different tables as follows:

```
 SELECT  crm_countries.country_name as Country,crm_support_inquiry.event_name as Event, crm_inquiry_perticipant.company as Company,crm_inquiry_perticipant.contact_name ContactPerson,crm_inquiry_perticipant.email, 

GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Expogroup, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Expogroup,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Abdas, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Abdas, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(AfricaDetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS AfricaDetails, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Kenyadetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Kenyadetails,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Findexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Findexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Dubaiexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Dubaiexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(IndiaExportNews, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS IndiaExportNews FROM ( SELECT inquiry_id,event_id,event_name,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 1 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Expogroup,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 2 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Abdas,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 3 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS AfricaDetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 4 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Kenyadetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 5 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Findexporters, CASE WHEN mailer_id = 6 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Dubaiexporters ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 7 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS IndiaExportNews FROM crm_support_inquiry )

 AS crm_support_inquiry, crm_inquiry_perticipant,  crm_countries where  crm_inquiry_perticipant.inquiry_id=crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id and  crm_countries.country_id=crm_inquiry_perticipant.country GROUP BY crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id, crm_support_inquiry.event_id,crm_support_inquiry.event_name
```

This gives the data for the ids which are equal on crm_perticipant_inquiry and crm_support_inquiry.

Now i want the data for all the ids in crm_perticipant_inquiry even if the data for those ids is not present in crm_support_inquiry it must return null.I used right outer join and changed the query as follows but i am not getting the required output. plzz help!!

```
 SELECT  crm_countries.country_name as Country,crm_support_inquiry.event_name as Event, crm_inquiry_perticipant.company as Company,crm_inquiry_perticipant.contact_name ContactPerson,crm_inquiry_perticipant.email, 

GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Expogroup, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Expogroup,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Abdas, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Abdas, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(AfricaDetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS AfricaDetails, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Kenyadetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Kenyadetails,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Findexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Findexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Dubaiexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Dubaiexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(IndiaExportNews, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS IndiaExportNews FROM

 ( SELECT inquiry_id,event_id,event_name,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 1 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Expogroup,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 2 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Abdas,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 3 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS AfricaDetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 4 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Kenyadetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 5 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Findexporters, CASE WHEN mailer_id = 6 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Dubaiexporters ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 7 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS IndiaExportNews FROM crm_support_inquiry )
 AS crm_support_inquiry right outer join crm_inquiry_perticipant on crm_inquiry_perticipant.inquiry_id=crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id,  crm_countries where crm_countries.country_id=crm_inquiry_perticipant.country GROUP BY crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id, crm_support_inquiry.event_id,crm_support_inquiry.event_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove crm_countries table from the query and see that you get the all the ids in crm_perticipant_inquiry. You can then add the crm_countries table later on. For example try this

```
SELECT  crm_support_inquiry.event_name as Event, 
crm_inquiry_perticipant.company as Company,
crm_inquiry_perticipant.contact_name ContactPerson,
crm_inquiry_perticipant.email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Expogroup, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Expogroup,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Abdas, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Abdas, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(AfricaDetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS AfricaDetails, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Kenyadetails, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Kenyadetails,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Findexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Findexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(Dubaiexporters, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS Dubaiexporters,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(IndiaExportNews, CHAR(200)) SEPARATOR '/') AS IndiaExportNews FROM

 ( SELECT inquiry_id,event_id,event_name,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 1 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Expogroup,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 2 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Abdas,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 3 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS AfricaDetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 4 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Kenyadetails,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 5 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Findexporters, CASE WHEN mailer_id = 6 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS Dubaiexporters ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 7 THEN CONCAT(Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS IndiaExportNews FROM crm_support_inquiry )
 AS crm_support_inquiry 
    right outer join crm_inquiry_perticipant on crm_inquiry_perticipant.inquiry_id=crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id 
GROUP BY crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id, 
crm_support_inquiry.event_id,
crm_support_inquiry.event_name;
```

Comment: I am getting the same output as before. No change